# nyc says "Unable to lookup source" in reports

Tags: typescript, code-coverage, istanbul, hardhat

I am generating coverage reports using `nyc` in Node 16.

However, for some reason, the coverage report (both lcov and html) is messed up, because the paths to the source files are wrong. They follow the pattern:

`<relative path>file:<absolute path><file name>`

e.g. `SF:src/rest/file:/home/<user>/code/<project>/src/rest/auth.ts` in `lcov.info`

Consequently, my html coverage reports show errors like

`Unable to lookup source: /home/<user>/code/<project>/src/rest/file:/home/<user>/code/<project>/src/rest/auth.ts (ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...`

for all files.

I found out, that the sourcemaps have paths starting with "file:///".

Also, in the "coverage" folder, there are obscure folders named "file:", which seem to resemble the absolute path with folders inside.

**I can't figure out why this is, but I want the reports to use relative paths to my project directory.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason: there recently was a patch update of `ts-node` from 10.8.0 to 10.8.1 - where they switched to File URIs in the source maps.

A downgrade to 10.8.0 solved the problem for me.

Regarding the bug/compatibility issue with nyc, there's an ongoing discussion in ts-node's repo: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1790